# Парсинг сайта с динамической типизацией без использования Selenium

Tags: python, requests, beautiful-soup, динамическая-типизация

Попал в какой-то тупик на самом деле, либо не до конца все просмотрел. Больше склоняюсь к первому конечно)

```
import requests


url = 'https://store.steampowered.com/specials'
s = requests.Session()
s.cookies.set('Steam_Language', 'russian', domain='store.steampowered.com')
r = s.get(url)
src = r.text

with open("index.html", "w", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    file.write(src)
```

Не особо вижу здесь смысл от кода, ну да ладно. Решил записать все в html файл только после того, как мне в результат вышел пустой массив. Просмотрел html файл и понял, что все, кроме заголовков на странице подгружается с сервера. Но не получается найти откуда именно. Помогите пожалуйста!

Нужны игры из этого блока:

[image: Нужны игры из этого блока]

Comment: По моему они подгружаются от сюда `<div id="application_config" style="display: none;"  data-config="...` вместо точек длинная строка содержащая все названия игр которые там появляются

Comment: Поправка в `data-ch_broadcasts_data_6="...`

Comment: @gord1402 да, они подгружаются здесь. но меня интересуют немного другие игры.  В `data-ch_broadcasts_data_6` видимо не те игры. Ведь при изменении офсета, данные в `data-ch_broadcasts_data_6` не изменяются, да и при сравнении я нашел много различий между теми играми. которые там, где мне надо. Сейчас внесу правки и добавлю фотку тех игр, которые мне надо парсить.

Comment: Вы можете использовать веб-api стима получить список `https://api.steampowered.com/ISteamApps/GetAppList/v2/` документация https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/webapi/ISteamApps#GetAppList

Comment: @gord1402 на сколько я понял - запрос вернет мне список всех доступных приложений/игр, а мне требуются все игры, на которые действует скидка

Comment: `https://store.steampowered.com/api/appdetails?appids=id1,id2...&cc=us&filters=price_overview` вместо id1,id2... вставляешь id полученные из GetAppList и смотришь если в ответе initial больше чем final

Comment: @gord1402 в целом схема рабочая, но безумно медленная. Завтра с утра попробую доработать код, надеюсь, что получится ускорить его. Ведь столько ждать на регулярной основе - бред. Спасибо за помощь в любом случае!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Получилось собрать все нужные данные, коих 10000, всего за 6 минут. Расследование можете наблюдать в комментариях к основному посту, все таки использовал web-api стима. Если вкратце, то делал запрос, который возвращал список всех существующих игр.

```
https://api.steampowered.com/ISteamApps/GetAppList/v2/
```

После чего узнал какое количество идентификаторов может принимать этот запрос

```
https://store.steampowered.com/api/appdetails?appids=&cc=ru&filters=price_overview
```

И на основе этого запроса создал цикл, который проверял по тысяче игр(максимальное количество идентификаторов) за раз и записывал идентификаторы скидочных игр в список. Таким образом получился рабочий код, который всего за 6 минут проверяет все 150000+ игр из стима.

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Правки внесены. Спасибо!